# Defining a new environment without spreading over two pages

Tags: math-mode, environments

I've definied an environment with

```
\newenvironment{definiere}{\begin{leftbar} \textbf{Definition:}\newline }{\end{leftbar}}
```

Unfortunately sometimes this environment is spread over two pages, where the left-bar is about 2cm long and "Definition" written as header, but the actual definition itself is on the next page.

I'm using this environment mostly like this:

```
\begin{definiere}
   \begin{equation}
     WMC=\sum_{i=1}^n {c_i} \label{eq:WMC}
   \end{equation}
\end{definiere}
```

I can avoid this behaviour by moving paragraphs below or above the definition, but sometimes it doesn't make sense anymore. My question is, does someone see a more elegant solution to my needs?

Comment: Would making it a floating environment solve your problem?

Comment: @Raphink: How ?

Comment: Please state what you want not what you don't want, especially in the title. You want an environment which doesn't break over multiple pages? Then say so in the title. At the moment the title means the exact opposite for me!

Comment: You are right, unfortunately I can not edit the title anymore. Sorry

Comment: @adnc: Of course you can edit the title: http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/16729/edit

Comment: @adnc: if you edit the post, you can change the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `\textbf{Definition}` is a title like a section title. Suppress the page break like `\section` does it:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{definiere}
  {\begin{leftbar}%
   \textbf{Definition:}\par\nobreak\@afterheading}
  {\end{leftbar}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: That works great!

Answer (score 1):

Ulrike's answer is probably the correct way of doing something like that. Another approach that seemed to work for me---you could pack everything inside a minipage. Hopefully, someone else can explain exactly why it worked.

```
\newenvironment{definiere}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\begin{leftbar} \textbf{Definition:}\newline }{\end{leftbar}\end{minipage}}
```